# Is this a Sobolev Norm?

Tags: normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

In this paper ([www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18683237](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18683237)) the Sobolev Norm is defined as follows 
$$
 ||f||_l = ||(1 - c \Delta)^{l/2}f||_{L2}
$$
$f$ is a function, $\Delta$ is the 2D Laplace and $l$, $c$ are factors.

I can't see how the formal definition of the Sobolev norm (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SobolevSpace.html) corresponds to the quoted norm... Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange, and thank you for posting this question. The norm given there is equivalent to the Sobolev norm $\|f\|_{H^\ell}$ (assuming $c > 0$), as an application of the Fourier transform shows.

Comment: That helped :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a special norm that generalizes the characterization of the $H^1$-norm by Fourier transform, this allows you to define the Hilbert-Sobolev spaces $H^s$ with $s \in \mathbb{R}$. That form is a consequence of this fact:

[Construction of Sobolev space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744090/construction-of-sobolev-space/1744113#1744113)

The constant $c$ depends on how you define the Fourier transform, in my case $c=1/4\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your link was what i needed. GREAT!

Comment: You are welcome.